# PHP Insert Into

Tags: php, html

I have a html form as such:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
    Mentees :<br>
    1. Student No: <input name="mentee1" type="text">
    <br>
    2. Student No: <input name="mentee2" type="text">
    <br>
    3. Student No: <input name="mentee3" type="text">
    <br>
    4. Student No: <input name="mentee4" type="text">
    <br>
    5. Student No: <input name="mentee5" type="text">
    <br>
    6. Student No: <input name="mentee6" type="text">
    <br>
    7. Student No: <input name="mentee7" type="text">
    <br>
    8. Student No: <input name="mentee8" type="text">
    <br>
    9. Student No: <input name="mentee9" type="text">
    <br>
    10. Student No: <input name="mentee10" type="text">
    </td>
</tr>
```

The user may enter all or a few of the mentees and submit.

Now here's a part of my PHP code:
(Sorry for the long and messy code)
The PHP is supposed to check if the $mentee1-10 posted is empty or null and make a query according to them, but I tried the code and it seems to only send $mentee1 and leave out the rest even if they are not empty.

```
if ($mentor1 != NULL || $mentor1 != "") {
    if ($mentor2 != NULL || $mentor2 != "") {
        if ($mentor3 != NULL || $mentor3 != "") {
            if ($mentor4 != NULL || $mentor4 != "") {
                if ($mentor5 != NULL || $mentor5 != "") {
                    if ($mentor6 != NULL || $mentor6 != "") {
                        if ($mentor7 != NULL || $mentor7 != "") {
                            if ($mentor8 != NULL || $mentor8 != "") {
                                if ($mentor9 != NULL || $mentor9 != "") {
                                    if ($mentor10 != NULL || $mentor10 != "") {
                                        $query_upload3 = "INSERT INTO mentor_student (staff_no, student_no) VALUES ('$staff_no', '$mentee1'),('$staff_no', '$mentee2'),('$staff_no', '$mentee3'),
                                        ('$staff_no', '$mentee4'),('$staff_no', '$mentee5'),('$staff_no', '$mentee6'),('$staff_no', '$mentee7'),('$staff_no', '$mentee8'),
                                        ('$staff_no', '$mentee9'),('$staff_no', '$mentee10')";
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    $query_upload3 = "INSERT INTO mentor_student (staff_no, student_no) VALUES ('$staff_no', '$mentee1'),('$staff_no', '$mentee2'),('$staff_no', '$mentee3'),
                                        ('$staff_no', '$mentee4'),('$staff_no', '$mentee5'),('$staff_no', '$mentee6'),('$staff_no', '$mentee7'),('$staff_no', '$mentee8'),
                                        ('$staff_no', '$mentee9')";
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                $query_upload3 = "INSERT INTO mentor_student (staff_no, student_no) VALUES ('$staff_no', '$mentee1'),('$staff_no', '$mentee2'),('$staff_no', '$mentee3'),
                                        ('$staff_no', '$mentee4'),('$staff_no', '$mentee5'),('$staff_no', '$mentee6'),('$staff_no', '$mentee7'),('$staff_no', '$mentee8')";
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            $query_upload3 = "INSERT INTO mentor_student (staff_no, student_no) VALUES ('$staff_no', '$mentee1'),('$staff_no', '$mentee2'),('$staff_no', '$mentee3'),
                                        ('$staff_no', '$mentee4'),('$staff_no', '$mentee5'),('$staff_no', '$mentee6'),('$staff_no', '$mentee7')";
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        $query_upload3 = "INSERT INTO mentor_student (staff_no, student_no) VALUES ('$staff_no', '$mentee1'),('$staff_no', '$mentee2'),('$staff_no', '$mentee3'),
                                        ('$staff_no', '$mentee4'),('$staff_no', '$mentee5'),('$staff_no', '$mentee6')";
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $query_upload3 = "INSERT INTO mentor_student (staff_no, student_no) VALUES ('$staff_no', '$mentee1'),('$staff_no', '$mentee2'),('$staff_no', '$mentee3'),
                                        ('$staff_no', '$mentee4'),('$staff_no', '$mentee5')";
                }
            }
            else {
                $query_upload3 = "INSERT INTO mentor_student (staff_no, student_no) VALUES ('$staff_no', '$mentee1'),('$staff_no', '$mentee2'),('$staff_no', '$mentee3'),('$staff_no', '$mentee4')";
            }

        }
        else {
            $query_upload3 = "INSERT INTO mentor_student (staff_no, student_no) VALUES ('$staff_no', '$mentee1'),('$staff_no', '$mentee2'),('$staff_no', '$mentee3')";
        }
    }
    else {
        $query_upload3 = "INSERT INTO mentor_student (staff_no, student_no) VALUES ('$staff_no', '$mentee1'),('$staff_no', '$mentee2')";
    }
}
else {
    $query_upload3 = "INSERT INTO mentor_student (staff_no, student_no) VALUES ('$staff_no', '$mentee1')";
}

if (mysqli_query($conn, $query_upload3) == TRUE) {
    echo "<strong>New record created successfully</strong><br>";
    echo "<a href=form_mentor.php>Add New Record</a>";
}
```

Comment: Can you check few like 2-3 mentee first to check your logic works or not.

Comment: If you're ever nesting 10 levels of `if`s and `else`s, chances are pretty high that you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not totally missing your point, how about something like this.  You can save yourself a lot of code repitition with some loops:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
    Mentees :
    <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) { ?>
        <br />
        <?php echo $i; ?>. Student No: <input name="mentee[]" type="text">
    <?php } ?>
    </td>
</tr>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['mentee'])) {
    $values = array();
    foreach ($_POST['mentee'] as $mentee) {
        $student_no = mysqli_real_escape_string($mentee);
        $values[] = "('$staff_no', '$student_no')";
    }

    if ($values) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO mentor_student (staff_no, student_no)
                  VALUES " . implode(',',$values);
        if (mysqli_query($conn, $query) == TRUE) {
            echo "<strong>New record created successfully</strong><br>";
            echo "<a href='form_mentor.php'>Add New Record</a>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow...

Let's see if I understood correctly. You're trying to insert a value depending on the sent values but they don't depend on each other? If that's the case I would do something like this :

```php
$arr = array();
$str = "";
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
      if(isset($value) && strlen($value) > 0) {
           $arr[] = "('$staff_no', ".$key.")";
      }
}
$str = implode(',', $arr);
$query_upload = "INSERT INTO mentor_student (staff_no, student_no) VALUES " . $str;
echo $query_upload;
```

Here I'm creating an array dynamically depending of which values the user sent and then joining them with a comma so I can have a query like yours.

Try it and you'll tell us.

Comment: If the PHP code were to contain other variables like $name, $place.
Will this still work?

Comment: You would have to see how to do it. In that case you should have posted a more complete case to start from there.

Answer (score 0):

You don't wanna do a condition inside a condition inside a condition like that...
If I understand what you wanna do, you wanna put it something like this:
(not the optimal way to do this, but try):

```
$tjek_if_ins = false;

if ($mentor1 != "") {
mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO mentor_student (staff_no, student_no) VALUES ('$staff_no', '$mentee1')");
$tjek_if_ins = true;
}
if ($mentor2 != "") {
mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO mentor_student (staff_no, student_no) VALUES ('$staff_no', '$mentee2')");
$tjek_if_ins = true;
}
if ($mentor3 != "") {
mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO mentor_student (staff_no, student_no) VALUES ('$staff_no', '$mentee3')");
$tjek_if_ins = true;
}
if ($mentor4 != "") {
mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO mentor_student (staff_no, student_no) VALUES ('$staff_no', '$mentee4')");
$tjek_if_ins = true;
}
if ($mentor5 != "") {
mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO mentor_student (staff_no, student_no) VALUES ('$staff_no', '$mentee5')");
$tjek_if_ins = true;
}
if ($mentor6 != "") {
mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO mentor_student (staff_no, student_no) VALUES ('$staff_no', '$mentee6')");
$tjek_if_ins = true;
}
if ($mentor7 != "") {
mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO mentor_student (staff_no, student_no) VALUES ('$staff_no', '$mentee7')");
$tjek_if_ins = true;
}
if ($mentor8 != "") {
mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO mentor_student (staff_no, student_no) VALUES ('$staff_no', '$mentee8')");
$tjek_if_ins = true;
}
if ($mentor9 != "") {
mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO mentor_student (staff_no, student_no) VALUES ('$staff_no', '$mentee9')");
$tjek_if_ins = true;
}
if ($mentor10 != "") {
mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO mentor_student (staff_no, student_no) VALUES ('$staff_no', '$mentee10')");
$tjek_if_ins = true;
}

if ($tjek_if_ins == true) {
echo "<strong>New record created successfully</strong><br>";
echo "<a href=form_mentor.php>Add New Record</a>";
}
else {
echo "Nothing was created...";
}
```